# Magento2 : Save Button Not Working in Admin Form Custom Module

Tags: magento2, php, module, javascript, custom

I am Working on A magento 2 custom Module
i have a Form as well a Product Grid in my form so i created tabs using block but Whenever 
i click on save button gives me Javascript Error

> TypeError: $.data(...) is undefined

Here is my form
**vendorName\moduleName\Block\Adminhtml\BackgroundImage\Edit\Form.php**

```
namespace vendor name\Module name\Block\Adminhtml\BackgroundImage\Edit;


class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function _prepareForm()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                    'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                    'method' => 'post',
                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
                ]
            ]
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Here is my Edit page where i Defined my Button 
**vendorName\moduleName\Block\Adminhtml\BackgroundImage\Edit.php**

```
namespace FvendorName\moduleName\Block\Adminhtml\BackgroundImage;


class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
{

    protected $_coreRegistry = null;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'backgroundimage_id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'FME_BackgroundImage';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_backgroundImage';
        parent::_construct();

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('FME_BackgroundImage::save')) {
            $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Save Image'));
            $this->buttonList->add(
                'saveandcontinue',
                [
                    'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
                    'class' => 'save',
                    'data_attribute' => [
                        'mage-init' => [
                            'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit', 'target' => '#edit_form'],
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
                -100
            );
        } else {
            $this->buttonList->remove('save');
        }


    }

    /**
     * Retrieve text for header element depending on loaded page
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('backgroundimage')->getId()) {
            return __(
                "Edit BackgroundImage '%1'",
                $this->escapeHtml($this->_coreRegistry->registry('backgroundimage')->getTitle())
            );
        } else {
            return __('New BackgroundImage');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check permission for passed action
     *
     * @param string $resourceId
     * @return bool
     */
    public function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
    }

    /**
     * Getter of url for "Save and Continue" button
     * tab_id will be replaced by desired by JS later
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function _getSaveAndContinueUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            'backgroundimage/*/save',
            ['_current' => true, 'back' => 'edit', 'active_tab' => '{{tab_id}}']
        );
    }

    public function getFormActionUrl()
    {
        if ($this->hasFormActionUrl()) {
            return $this->getData('form_action_url');
        }

        return $this->getUrl('*/*/save');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare layout
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
     */
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->_formScripts[] = "
            function toggleEditor() {
                if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('page_content') == null) {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'page_content');
                } else {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'page_content');
                }
            };
        ";
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: do u see any error in console?

Comment: I got this in console TypeError: $.data(...) is undefined

Comment: u have extented your edit class from "\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container" u should extend it from this class \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget

Comment: Now getting this error Notice: Undefined property: Vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\BackgroundImage\Edit::$buttonList

Comment: u have used  $this->buttonList object which does not belongs to any other class.

Comment: i have alreadt overloaded this class \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context, in my constructor of Edit Class

Comment: well, the object buttonList does not belong to \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context.

Answer (score 0):

Check $form->setUseContainer(true); in your file if it is there either remove or set to false.